# How can I block a service without uninstalling the app?

Tags: services

There was a similar question (How can I prevent services from running in the background? ) but it has been marked answered without an answer to the OP. And so, I'm asking a narrower question because I really want to block quite a few services I don't want to run. So, I have an app and need it, but to my surprise it keeps a service running, and no option to control it. I use the app say twice a month and don't want cpu and memory locked all the time. E.g. Rocket Player or 3D Live Weather or Maps.

Answer (score 3):

There is an app called [Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify&hl=en) in Play Store. What it does is stopping the **selected** apps when the screen is locked. Will be very helpful in your case.
*Note:  Rooting is not required.*

Comment: I tried Greenify for some time but the net result on my battery life was zero or negative.  This is android 4.2.1.  Has anyone seen similar behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I m using a 4.2.2 jellybean device.
I m suffered from same problem,but donn't worry i help you,
You have some options
1. You uninstall the app when you need install with cache by Es file explorer.
2. If you have root permission so frost it you can use some applications like titanium backup & restpre,lucky patcher,hide it pro...
It can freeze them when ever you want them unfreeze it...

Answer (score 0):

I second [MANI's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/92316/16575) to use *Greenify*. However, if you rarely use that app, there might be another interesting alternative:

You can use [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) to freeze an app, and create a specific shortcut to that on the desktop (chose *Shortcut › Titanium Backup*). The icon would show a locked app then. You could use it as any other app shortcut: it would unfreeze and launch the app, then freeze it again.

Similar behavior can be achieved using [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker), which has the possibility to change the "package state" (at least when using the *Secure Settings* addon).

Note that both options require the device being rooted – while *Greenify* in most cases works even without root access being available.